# Jquery returnfalse; not working

Tags: jquery

I have a tabbed navigation box on the sidebar of a wordpress blog. When clicking in the tabs to navigate, the page jumps to the top.

The code has the return false and also tried the href=# onclick=returnfalse; but it didn't work.

**Thank you!** (will appreciate if you point out the mistake in the code as i'm totally rookie with jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('ul.tabNav a').click(function() {
  var curChildIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length + 1;
  $(this).parent().parent().children('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).parent().addClass('current');
  $(this).parent().parent().next('.tabContainer').children('.current').show('fast',function() {
   $(this).removeClass('current');
   $(this).parent().children('div:nth-child('+curChildIndex+')').hide('fast',function() {
    $(this).addClass('current');
   });
  });
  return false;        
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`

```
 $('ul.tabNav a').click(function(evt) {    
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
 );
```

see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: thank you guys! I tried that before, it works on a "test file" but the problem persists when I migrate the code to my wordpress theme...

Comment: look at the javascript console, maybe you've some errors inside your click() handler

Comment: Solved! SOLUTION (weird but it worked): load the script from an external file, don't put the code in <head>... thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using preventDefault

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/